# How to bind data to the viewModel using MVVM architecture in Android

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding

```
    val binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this@MainActivity,R.layout.activity_main)
```

ViewModel

```
    var viewModel:LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel("Enter Email Address","Enter password","Log-in")
```

but when I am doing like this

```
    binding.Login=viewModel
```

**it points to Login and says unresolved references.**

activity_main.xml

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="Login"
        type="com.example.itstym.logina.LoginViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="clickListener"
        type="com.example.itstym.logina.interface.loginClickListener" />

</data>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome, Back"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>

    <EditText
        app:error="@{login.errorEmail}"
        android:hint="@{login.emailHint}"
        android:text="@{login.userEmailAddress}"
        android:id="@+id/user_email_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        app:error="@{login.errorPassword}"
        android:text="@{login.userPassword}"
        android:hint="@{login.passwordHint}"
        android:id="@+id/user_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_email_address"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="@{(v)->clickListener.onSubmitButtonClick()}"
        android:text="@{login.loginButtonText}"
        android:id="@+id/login_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Or Sign In"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_submit"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log in with google plus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log in with facebook"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What could be the possible error? Here we pass the viewModel class instance to the xml data variable.

I am newbie in MVVM architecture.

Actually, I am following [this link](https://github.com/khakhranisagar/LoginModuleMVVM/blob/master/src/main/java/sagarkhakhrani/loginmodule/MainActivity.java)  Here in the mainActivity it is calling set login () but when I am trying to call, it shows Unresolved references. –

Comment: i don't know kotlin but i think there is a difference "Login" in variable initialization and login in accesing via view model in views

Comment: Do I post my ViewModel class here( if it helps in understanding)? @Shubham

Comment: @Shubham Actually this is set login function of ViewModel but I am not able to find any setLogin function in ViewModel.

Comment: Actually I am following this link https://github.com/khakhranisagar/LoginModuleMVVM/tree/master/src/main/java/sagarkhakhrani/loginmodule Here in the mainActivity it is calling set login () but when I am trying to call, it shows Unresolved references.

Comment: try changing name="Login" to name="login" and assoiciated viewholder assignment. As You have defined variable name with Login and you are accesing via @{login.errorEmail} that is login

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing like its done in the example you are following

```
binding.setLogin(viewModel);
```

Data binding creates the ***setLogin()*** method for this variable declared in activity_main.xml

```
<variable
        name="Login"
        type="com.example.itstym.logina.LoginViewModel" />
```

If still it gives the same error, check for spelling in the package name of your variable and the declared LoginViewModel class.